# preg_replace - replace everything inbetween figure tags

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace

I am working on a Wordpress site and I don't want images to appear in the excerpt.

It was quite easy with:

```
preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content);
```

to delete images but since images are wrapped within `<figure>` tags with a caption, I tried to alter the pattern to

```
/(<figure.*?[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/figure)/i
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you simply use the_excerpt(); function which only shows the text of content by filtering images and links.

Comment: because that would just end up in 2 hours more work instead of 6 hours of research and 10 min work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `>` at the end

check here [phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/inD)

```
preg_replace("/(<figure.*?[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/figure>)/i", "", $input);
```

Comment: I also played around at regex101 with `<figure(.*)<\/figure>` which works over there but not on my live site. Could it be a wordpress thing?

Comment: Are you sur u using it like this `preg_replace("/(<figure.*?[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/figure>)/i", "deleted", $input_lines);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.*?`, also there're no uses of the capture groups:

```
~$result = preg_replace("~<figure[^>]*>.*?</figure>~i", "", $input);
```